# Is there a way to work with records that you marked in table on X++?

Tags: select, axapta, multi-select, x++

I want to work with table records that is selected (Marked), Example - I have 10 records in table and i mark 5 of them. Expected - when i work with selected records, it should look only on that 5 records, not whole 10.

So far i have this code that selects all records:

```
while select Table
                where table.JournalId == table.JournalId
```

Is there a way to make it select only marked records, not everything?
That select is writen in class. I need to get those marked records into that class where that select is writen...

Comment: When you write "mark", do you mean the records are selected in the user interface in a grid? If, yes, the answer depends on the version of the application you are on. Assuming you are on version [tag:dynamics-ax-2012] or newer, take a look at the `MultiSelectionHelper` class (see http://metinemreenglish.blogspot.com/2016/01/axapta-why-sometimes.html for more information).
Please [edit] your question with new information instead of answering with a comment. This will increase your chances of receiving an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the formdatasource object into the class that is selecting the records, and then use the MultiSelectionHelper to loop through the selected records on the formdatasource.

In the example below, the object `salesTableFormDataSource` needs to be passed in from the form to the class you are using. Obviously replace that with whatever your datasource/table needs are.

```
MultiSelectionHelper selection = MultiSelectionHelper::construct();
selection.parmDatasource(salesTableFormDataSource);
SalesTable salesTable = selection.getFirst();

while (salesTable)
{
    //do something with your table buffer.
    salesTable = selection.getNext();
}
```